# How do I make it so that a drop-down menu only shows at half or quarter window size?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Like on [IGN](https://uk.ign.com/) I would like to make it so that within my E-Magazine I can change the top tabs from the line layout, to a drop down menu, like IGN does when the website window is made too small.

I haven't tried this, I have researched it but haven't found anything that I have felt comfortable trying. However, here is the current code I have:

```html
<h5 id="tabdiv"> <a href="index.html">Home</a> &emsp;&emsp; <a href="reviews.html">Reviews</a> &emsp;&emsp; <a href="interviews.html">interviews</a> &emsp;&emsp; <a href="apply.html">Apply</a> &emsp;&emsp; <a href="login register.html">Login / Sign Up</a>
```

And [here](https://prntscr.com/mva75j) is the output of the code.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please show your existing code with an example what the curent output is! Right now your question is a bit vague, I don't really know what you refer to.

Comment: What attempts have you made?  Generally, when you ask a question on here, we expect that you at least attempt to answer the question yourself, and that you post an example of the code that you've tried.

Comment: @Magiixk please add this to your question

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to make a dropdown with HTML

```css
select.example {
  max-width: 15%;
}
```

```html
<select class="example">
  <option value="stackoverflow">Stackoverflow</option>
  <option value="google">Google</option>
  <option value="yahoo">Yahoo</option>
  <option value="wired">Wired</option>
  <option value="theoatmeal">The Oatmeal</option>
</select>
```

With your stuff being in an E-zine, the `style=""` tag will probably have to be utilized. `<select class="example" style="max-width: 15%;">`

---

Without knowing more all I can do it give you basics that you should honestly know before you even post here. You have to learn and make your own attempt so we can see what you need exactly.

Posting un-related code that is contrary to what you're trying to do doesn't really help us help you much.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking for something like the max-width but for the page, so that the drop-down menu only appears at about half size, and disappears above it, because of the size of the text in my E-Magazine size it starts to overlap and look messy below about 40% which is why i wanted to add the drop down menu but only below this point.

Comment: max-width is really your best bet. 

Then you'll probably need javascript to do anything fancier.

Comment: yeah, one of my problems is my own coding limitations. I will try this, i am a very cautious coder as i will most of the time prefer not to try things in fear of not being able to fix then even using CTRL+Z, i will try this so thank you for the help.

Comment: After trying this, the menu works but not how i wanted it too, this is helping but I'm looking for more of a vertical drop down, the IGN link is there for example so please be sure to view it.